# Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", Proposition 3.12

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, manifolds, tensors

As I tried to prove the following proposition by myself:

[image]

I got this:

$$(\tau(Af))(v_1,\dots,v_k)=(Af)(v_{\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\tau(k)})=\sum_\sigma (\operatorname {sgn} \sigma) f(v_{\sigma (\tau(v_1)),\dots,\sigma(\tau(v_k))})=\sum_\sigma (\operatorname {sgn} \sigma)(\sigma \tau) f(v_1,\dots,v_k),$$
which is not the same as the proof in the book claims ($\sigma \tau \ne \tau \sigma$). Is this a typo, or did I miss something?

Of course both mine and his partial results give the same answer, but I was wondering whether I (or Tu) applied definitions incorrectly. In my understanding, his first equality does not follow directly from the definition.

(Note that $\sigma f(v_1,\dots,v_k)=f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})$ by definition.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$

I think that you and the book are both correct.  You have

$$\sum\limits_{\sigma}( \sgn \sigma)(\sigma \tau) f$$

The expression in the sum does not change if you replace every $\sigma$ in the sum with $\sigma  \tau^{-1}$:

$$\sum\limits_{\sigma} \sgn(\sigma \tau^{-1})( \sigma) f$$

Now $\sgn \sigma \tau^{-1} = \sgn \sigma \sgn \tau^{-1} = \sgn \sigma \sgn \tau$, so you can factor out $\sgn \tau$:

$$\sgn \tau \sum\limits_{\sigma} (\sgn \sigma)\sigma f = \sgn \tau Af$$

Comment: Thank you. I do realize that my computations eventually give the desired result, but is it correct that application of definitions gives my partial result and not Tu's? The RHS of his first equality looks unmotivated since (if I'm not mistaken) that's not what one gets directly by applying definitions. (What one gets instead, according to my computations, is the same with the order of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ switched.)

Comment: @Cary Well, since $Af=\sum_{\sigma} (\sgn\sigma)\sigma f$ defines how $A$ works, we have $$ \tau(Af)=\tau\left(\sum_{\sigma}(\sgn \sigma)\sigma f\right)=\sum_\sigma (\sgn\sigma) \tau(\sigma f). $$ Seems motivated to me.

Comment: @anon But on the other hand, for any $k$-tensor $g$, $$(\tau g)(v_1,\dots,v_k)=g(v_{\tau(1)},\dots v_{\tau(k)}),$$ and if we apply this to $g=Af$, we get $\sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) \sigma(\tau f)$.

Comment: @Cary Correct. You do it one way, you get one thing, you do it another way, you get another thing. Therefore they're equal. The purpose of my comment was to explain why the RHS was perfectly motivated. (In fact, in my opinion better, since it shows that bothering with the definition of $S_n$ acting on $f$ wasn't even necessary to show the result.) You're trying to show two functions are equal by showing they're equal at all inputs. The text's argument shows that these two things are equal simply by virtue of how group actions work, regardless of the fact the two things are functions.

Comment: @anon Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$The confusion is in your second equality where you say
$$ (Af)(v_{\tau(1)}, \dots, v_{\tau(k)}) = \sum_\sigma (\sgn \sigma)(\sigma f)(v_{\tau(1)}, \dots, v_{\tau(k)}) = \sum_\sigma (\sgn \sigma)f(v_{\sigma(\tau(1))}, \dots, v_{\sigma(\tau(k))}). $$

Actually, following the definitions gives $(\sigma f)(v_{\tau(1)}, \dots, v_{\tau(k)}) = f(v_{\tau(\sigma(1))}, \dots, v_{\tau(\sigma(k))})$. Note that Tu uses this same step in the proof of Lemma 3.11.